# OpenCV : Replace Mask with background color

Tags: numpy, opencv

I would like to apply a mask operation on an image where my ultimate goal to remove the mask completely and replace it with the background color

Here is an Image Sample :

[image]

The Mask:

[image]

I have used `cv2.bitwise_not` but the output is not a complete removal

```
res = cv2.bitwise_not(img,img,mask=closex)
```

[image]

I assume that there is a numpy operation can do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using:

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread("theBaseImage.jpg", 1)
mask = cv2.imread("theImageToUseAsMask.jpg", 1)
whiteOut = cv2.add(mask, img) #add your images, making the desired regions white
cv2.imwrite("maskedImage.jpg", whiteOut)
```

This results in the following image:

[image]

Comment: Perfect, I haven't think about adding them although the masked parts are white.
Thanks!

Comment: @ahmedosama glad I could help :)